# How to fix the Autowired dependencies failing in spring-mvc Hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hello (i am a new Spring MVC Hibernate developper) and i am working on a user regestration application in Spring MVC and Hibernate using Netbeans. I have a problem and i can not resolve it; it's @Autowired and beans problem.

This my Entity, `User`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

/* attributes */
@Column(name = "Username")
private String userName;
@Column(name = "Email")
private String email;
@Column(name = "Firstname")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "LastName")
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "BirthDate")
private String birthDate;
@Column(name = "PhoneNumber")
private String phoneNumber;
@Column(name = "PWHash")
private String pwHash;
}
```

The DAO interface

```
package com.Etravals.DAO;
import com.Etravels.Model.User;
public interface UserDAO {

    public void addUser(User user);
}
```

DAO Impl:

```
import com.Etravels.Model.User;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        Session session = getSession();
        session.save(user);
    }
}
```

and service inteface :

```
package com.Etravels.Service;
import com.Etravels.Model.User;

public interface UserService {
    public void addUser(User user);
}
```

Service Impl :

```
package com.Etravels.Service;
import com.Etravals.DAO.UserDAO;
import com.Etravels.Model.User;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{    

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userdao;

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {         
        userdao.addUser(user);
    }
}
```

My HomeController :

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String showIndex(){
        return "acceuil";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addUser(@ModelAttribute("userFormSignUp") User user){
        userService.addUser(user);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }
}
```

and this is my dispatcher-servlet.xml file :

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.Etravels" />
    <!-- Getting Database properties -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/resources/img/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**" location="/resources/styles/"/> 
    <mvc:resources mapping="/javascript/**" location="/resources/javascript/"/> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- View Resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- DataSource -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.Etravels.Model"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />       
</beans>
```

This is what I have as an error from Apache Tomcat server log :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
  Error creating bean with name 'homeController':
  Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Could not autowire field:
    private com.Etravels.Service.UserService com.Etravels.Controller.HomeController.userService; nested exception is
      org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
      Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl':
      Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
        Could not autowire field:
        private com.Etravals.DAO.UserDAO com.Etravels.Service.UserServiceImpl.userdao; nested exception is
          org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
          No qualifying bean of type [com.Etravals.DAO.UserDAO] found for dependency:
          expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
          {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProc ....
```

Comment: Try adding @Repository on UserDAO interface..!!

Comment: The `UserDAO` and `UserDAOImpl` are in different packages, but there is no `import` for the `UserDAO` interface in `UserDAOImpl`. Are you sure it is implementing the correct interface?

Comment: in which package is you DAO implementation?

Comment: @Akash ... yes they are (UserDAO and UserDAOImpl) in the com.Etravels.DAO package;

Comment: can you share your git repo?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    @Autowired(required=true)
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

In UserDAOImpl class.

Comment: Then try changing your tomcat or appropriate SDK